# Can't select columns from database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables:

- `[Users]: UserId, Name...`
- `[Topics]: TopicId, CreatorUserId...`
- `[Comments]: CommentId, TopicId...`.

Now, I'd like to select the creators of the most popular topics according to this mechanism:
get the comments, which is newer than the specified date. Group those comments by the creator of the topic, and order by the number of rows in the groups.

However, I'm not sure that my query follows this logic(it seems according to the results, but I have only a few users and topics), but the main problem is that when I want to select the name of the user (`Users.Name`), I get an error:

> *Column '[TestDatabase].[dbo].[Users].[Name]' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

T-SQL query:

```
SELECT 
   Users.UserId, Users.Name, COUNT(Users.UserId) as RowCountInGroup
FROM [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Users]
INNER JOIN [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Topics] ON Topics.CreatorUserId = Users.UserId
INNER JOIN [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Comments] ON Comments.TopicId = Topics.TopicId
WHERE 
   Comments.CreationDate > CAST('14 SEPTEMBER 2012' as DateTime)
GROUP BY Users.UserId
ORDER BY RowCountInGroup DESC
```

Thanks for helping me.

EDIT: I've copied the original error message. I need to select the Email, the City, etc columns from the User, so I'm not sure that adding all of these to the `group by` clause is the best solution.

Comment: The error and the SQL don't appear match up - are you sure the error is not about the `Users.Name` column?

Comment: You have to group on Users.Name as well, which'd kind of explain the error you're getting, even if the error text doesn't match up with what your query is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to group by both columns (or in general: all columns) that you select (that are not aggregated by the `COUNT` aggregate operator):

```
SELECT 
   Users.UserId, Users.Name, COUNT(Users.UserId) as RowCountInGroup
FROM [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Users]
INNER JOIN [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Topics] ON Topics.CreatorUserId = Users.UserId
INNER JOIN [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Comments] ON Comments.TopicId = Topics.TopicId
WHERE 
   Comments.CreationDate > CAST('14 SEPTEMBER 2012' as DateTime)
GROUP BY 
   Users.UserId, Users.Name   <=== you need to add "Users.Name" here!
ORDER BY RowCountInGroup DESC
```

Comment: Yes, I tought so, but I need to select at least five columns. Users.City, Users.Email... Is this the only way?

Comment: @laszlokiss88: yes - that's the way to do it. The only way to do it.

Comment: @laszlokiss88 > yeah ...way to go

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both UserId and Name in your group by clause

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
SELECT a.UserId, b.Name, a.RowCountInGroup
FROM
    (SELECT Users.UserId, COUNT(Users.UserId) as RowCountInGroup
    FROM [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Users]
    INNER JOIN [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Topics] 
    ON Topics.CreatorUserId = Users.UserId
    INNER JOIN [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Comments] ON
    Comments.TopicId = Topics.TopicId
    WHERE Comments.CreationDate > CAST('14 SEPTEMBER 2012' as DateTime)
    GROUP BY Users.UserId
    ORDER BY RowCountInGroup DESC) a
LEFT JOIN [TestDatabase].[dbo].[Users] b ON b.UserId = a.UserId
```

Anytime you include a column with an aggregate, you must `GROUP BY` that column:

```
SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(col3)
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2
```